# IE:Textarea cursor not blinking, when focussing on textarea, when using TAB to move to next cell

Tags: javascript, css, cursor, tinymce, internet-explorer-9

I have a `textarea` defined in jsp. I am inserting a normal table using tinymce plugin.
Now while i press TAB to move to next cell within the table, my cursor doesnt display blinking but i can still type and the cursor suddenly shows up blinking and then again when i press TAB to move to the next cell, the cursor wont blink until i start typing and so on.

Any clue on how to display the blinking cursor when TAB is pressed to move to the next cell?

P.S. If i click on a particular cell using my mouse, then the cursor blinks and is ready for typing but doesnt have the similar behavior on pressing TAB.

Please Help.

Comment: sounds like a bug in IE... who would have thought right. might just have to wait for an update or find a way to submit a bug report to MS.

Comment: any possible work around for it?